# Understanding IOS8 size classes

Tags: ios, xcode, size-classes

I have been playing around on Xcode with size classes to try and make sense of it. The problem I have is that many different sized phones all fit into the same size class (like all iPhones in portrait) so I can't home in on a 3.5 inch screen for example. This is frustrating as I would like to change the layout constraints between phones rather than just classes as obviously I need to make the gaps between things larger or the buttons slightly bigger to keep everything in proportion. I don't know if it is something I have missed but it seems the only way I can do this is by creating every single layout constraint I want to change as an outlet and then testing in code for each phone and updating it using a rough estimate and run the thing on the simulator.

In Summary, how can I adjust the constraints based on the size of a device, when they're all in the same class? Using a percentage/proportional constraint should give me the result I'm after.

Answer (score 3):

Apple have designed it so that you don't have to think about specific devices. The idea is that you use auto layout so that each screen automatically adjusts to the available space. Size classes is an extension of that so when you get a lot of extra space you can do something slightly different.

If you want to customise your layout to specific devices, you can. Pretty much as you describe it. However, what happens next year when Apple release the iPad Pro and a 4.3" iPod touch (you read about it here first)? In general, there is no need to hard code spacing and sizes; your interface should scale to use the space available, and that's what auto layout and size classes give you.

It's certainly harder to think it terms of constraints rather than a list of known screen sizes, but it should be worth it.

Comment: I see what you mean, I don't see any scaling behaviour with Auto layout but I am thinking this is probably because I have put constraints on nearly everything in my UI (size and position relative to other elements) so Xcode probably looks at it and thinks it shouldn't ever change. I am probably not quite thinking about the design correctly in this case by being too rigid with constraints

Comment: If you're defining constraints for both size and location then, yes, there's not much scope for your interface to scale! Much of the time you can just use the "intrinsic size" of interface elements and just define the spacing between them. A UILabel, for example, knows its own height; you don't need to define it.

Comment: Just to add to this, I took the constraints away from the ui but no success, when previewing the app in iPhone 6 the buttons are hidden off the screen at the bottom out of view. It seems the only way I can have them be on the iPhone 6 screen is to add constraints (say 20 from the bottom edge) which takes me back to the original problem of now being stuck with no changes in position for larger screen.

Comment: I think you're going to have to explain what you're actually trying to achieve. Auto layout is _designed_ to allow you to sensibly scale a design from one screen size to another, so either you're trying to do something that isn't possible or you're using it incorrectly. I can talk in generalities but without know what you're trying to do I can't tell which.

Comment: lets say I have an app with five buttons near the bottom of the screen, if I run it in an iPhone 6 I would like those buttons to be in a similar proportion to where they were on the iPhone 5, If they were 20 from the bottom that might have to be 30 etc. similarly the button dimensions might have to scale appropriately. all the things auto layout should handle I would have thought. When I run it though none of that happens, the buttons are now missing having fallen off the bottom of the screen if you get my meaning

Comment: Off the top of my head I'm not sure how you'd increase the spacing depending on the screen size (then again, I'm not sure why you'd want to do that).

Comment: Check the console for constraints being broken as it sounds like you have too many, with iOS breaking the bottom constraint in order to make something work. Buttons 20 point from the bottom should be easy. You can easily make the width of all the buttons equal.

Comment: Thank you.. I suppose If you didn't increase spacing then everything would look a bit squashed?

Answer (score 1):

Well, Size Class has many advantages. It depends on how people viewing it. In specific to your question there is a way to change for all `iPhones in Portrait` and all `iPhones below 4.7` inch Size in portrait.Below is the image of that. I can understand supporting 3.5 inch screen with size class is difficult. Setting a proper constraint and using the below class will help you to achieve it.

[image]