# Set app size to native iPhone screen size xCode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, size, native

Now, before all you angry people say "hOLY DUCK THIS IS A DUPLICATE", just wait. I've seen at least 10 articles on this, NONE of which have been a help. My issue is im trying to make my iPhone app (xcode 8, swift 3.1, iOS 9 deployment)
match all screen sizes and set the app size to the NATIVE screen size on the device. I've seen the launchscreen articles, and they have been no help because they aren't specific. If somebody could either provide a tutorial or link one so I can figure this out, that would be great. Thanks all

Comment: Can you describe your problem more clearly?  What have you tried?  Any of the template apps in Xcode will create an app like this.  The simplest and best approach is to use a launch storyboard rather than launch images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding IOS8 size classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375082/understanding-ios8-size-classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set the constraints for your views.

Here's a tutorial specifically for XCode 8:
https://www.appcoda.com/auto-layout-guide/

Here's another for Adaptive Layouts:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started

At their most basic, constraints lock parts of the view to known areas (top, bottom, left, right) on the screen.  Compounding constraints can be helpful for specific problems, but they get complicated quickly. If you're having problems getting them to work properly, I have found it works best to remove all of the constraints and start again with something simple and increase complexity as needed.